# How to replace MicroStack external network (10.20.20.0/24) to our own LAN IP subnet (192.168.0.0/24)

Tags: 16.04, juju, openstack, canonical

I've deployed MicroStack as per [guideline](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/microstack-get-started#2-install-microstack) and by default all the IP (dashboard horizon, url api, etc) is using external network 10.20.20.0/24 and the interface br-ex is using 10.20.20.1. The deployment of MicroStack is automatically set everything. I'm not able to access dashboard horizon or instances via my LAN subnet (192.168.0.0/24).
How could I change default external network 10.20.20.0 subnet to follow my own LAN subnet.
Appreciate help and advise. Thank you.

---

This is my environment setup:-

Windows10 VMWAREWorkstation ---- VM UBUNTU1604 ----Microstack

I really hope someone who already deployed microstack or someone who run microstack on their own IP, appreciate for your comments and help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I access the dashboard through tunneling:

```
sudo ssh -i <ssh-key> -N -L 8001:10.20.20.1:80 <user>@<server-ip>
```

Source: [MicroStack: Collection of pro tips](https://microstack.run/docs/pro-tips)

To forward traffic, use static routing to the MicroStack machine.

Comment: Hi Ramy, thanks for your advise, now I can access dashboard from my LAN pc but I have to create tunneling before can access it. I would like to have the option to have clean external network using my LAN subnet instead of default 10.20.20.0/24. I can have custom setting using openstack packstack for example...but for microstack I'm not sure how it can be done. Im thinking to remove default external network and edit br-ex to follow my LAN subnet but not sure if this is doable or not. Pls advise any. Thank you